# How can I consolidate N different workbooks to one workbook with N sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I convert or combine my 24 separate  workbooks  (1 monthly for the past 2 years) to 24 worksheets on the same workbook? I'd prefer not using additional software or programming or coding; I'm unskilled at computers.

Comment: What do you mean by 24 separate Spreadsheet Files are they 24 Workbook? And how many Sheets they does have one or more that one since you want to combine them into 24 TABS in one Workbook!!

Comment: @RajeshS Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the new workbook which is going to hold all your sheets. 
Now open the first of your 24 workbooks, right-click the tab and select "Move or Copy".
[image]
A dialogue box will open. Select the new workbook, where you want the new sheet to go (likely at the end) and press OK.
Repeat the process another 23 times, and voilá.